# Convert a JWT token into SAML assertion in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, saml

We have an application using Azure AD B2C which gets user claims as JWT. We have a requirement to integrate Oracle Finance app within the application using Single Sign On (SSO).

Basically, I tried the steps in the following document and was able to get SAML assertion:
[Register a SAML application in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers)

But the above would require users to sign in again using B2C. We want the signed in users to be able to reach Oracle Finance application without logging in again.

Is it possible to convert the received JWT token into SAML assertion to be passed to Oracle application?

Comment: It is possible to generate SAML token from JWT token. You need to enable Session Management between 2 policies. 

Refer this link for Session Management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you login to one OIDC app via B2C policy, then try to login to a SAML App, you will automatically get SSO as long as the Identity Provider used to sign in is available in both policies. Make sure you are not passing any prompt parameter or forceauthn parameter to B2C.